# Make Spinctrl selected when activated in WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have 4 spinctrls in my app. When I click on them, I want all their 
content to be selected instantly. And another thing is, I need to make 
them tab traversal. Can you help me with some sort of code to do this 
task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch EVT_SPIN or EVT_SPINCTRL and in your handler, you can select all the values by calling each of the control's GetValue method. In the wxPython demo, it seems to support tab traversal. I'm not sure what's going on with yours. Did you try the FloatSpin widget as an alternative?

Comment: Actually, what I want is the same as what happens when we double click on a spin ctrl. I need to do it with just one click.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? I assume you can use SetSelection or something similar to select the text...

Comment: First, I need to catch click event on spinctrl but it doesnt seem possible from what I have read so far on the net. If I could do that, I could use SetSelection. Is it possible with floatspin?